# getting an error - use of self in property access'style' before self.init initializes self

Tags: swift3

```
private extension UIAlertAction {
    convenience init(title: String?, 
                preferredStyle: UIAlertActionStyle, buttonIndex:Int, 
                tapBlock:((UIAlertAction,Int) -> Void)?) { 
        self.init(title: title, style: style) {
            (action:UIAlertAction) in
            if let block = tapBlock {
                block(action,buttonIndex)
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's exactly what is says on the tin: You can't use a property before its initialized.

You're passing the value `style` to the designated initializer, which sets the value of `style. Perhaps you meant to pass`preferredStyle` instead?